How to install TeXiFy-IDEA on Mac M1 (Silicon)?
I'm trying to install TeXiFy-IDEA on a Mac M1 (Silicon) following this guide.
It's not clear to me which SDK I should choose.
Choosing several, and indicating the route shown in the guide, I always get the error:
Could not find **route**/pdflatex

For example:

Has anyone installed TeXiFy-IDEA on a Mac with the M1 chip? Is there anything else I need to install in particular? How should I specify the SDK?
Edit
I installed MacTex from Homebrew executing this command at terminal:
brew install --cask mactex

Now IntelliJ IDEA detectsTeX Live SDK TeX Live 2024. But when I create a new LaTeX project it remains in a background task Updating indexes that never ends.


That seems like an IDE. Did you install LaTeX as well? On Mac I'd probably recommend installing MacTeX (see tug.org/mactex)_

I believe TeXify is a front-end/GUI to a TeX distribution. To actually compile a LaTeX document, you need both a front-end and a TeX distribution The two most commonly used TeX distributions on MacOS platforms are TeXLive and MikTeX.

@daleif I installed MacTex from HomeBrew with brew install --cask mactex. Now, I have no idea which SDK I should select in this case, nor in which folder I should indicate the SDK installation location. Neither of them work.

@daleif It seems that the installation was not completed on the first run of brew install --cask mactex. I have run this command in the terminal a second time and after a few installations, it now detects TeX Live SDK TeX Live 2024. However, when I try to create a new LaTeX project the project is created, but in the background there is a task that never ends: Updating indexes

I have no idea what that IDE does. It might also not be a good idea to install MacTeX via homebrew, especially if they make it like they do on Debian where certain configuration tools are crippled.

@daleif Thank you. How do you recommend I install it?

Install proper MacTeX, tug.org/mactex, yes it is rather big. It it is the non cripped version. I'd also have a look at what exactly that IDE is doing. Especially what is it running while "Updating indexes". Some of these tools are doing confusing stuff behind your back.

@daleif fyi brew just pulls the whole mactex installation package from CTAN, no crippling involved

@DG' there is another one that ends up installing something similar to the cripped Debian one.

@daleif I guess you are thinking of the texlive formula from homebrew. The texlive formula indeed disables updates etc. and can't be recommended.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm not on mac so brew and homebrew are diferent things?

@daleif In this context, homebrew and brew mean the same thing. homebrew is the name of the package manager, brew is the name of the corresponding command line program.

@daleif a bit simplified, but basically brew is to homebrew what tlmgr is to texlive

The problem was that the first run of brew install --cask mactex (after a long wait) apparently downloaded the packages, but did not install the software.
Running the brew install --cask mactex command a second time started an installation process that was also lengthy, but less so than the first one and did install the packages.
After that second run, IntelliJ automatically detected TeX Live SDK TeX Live 2024.

As for the subsequent error of Updating indexes, that was caused by outdated software.
It was resolved by doing the following:

Update all LaTeX packages by running this command in Terminal:
 sudo tlmgr update --self --all


Update IntelliJ IDEA to its latest version (2024.2.4)

Update TeXify to its latest version (0.9.7)


With these three updates the problem has been solved.
